# Change "Add To Homescreen" pop up title for PWA

Tags: javascript, html, progressive-web-apps

I am wondering: is there any way to change the default `Add To Homescreen` popup title?

I am not using the mini-bar banner that Chrome on Android has, because if the user accidentally dismisses it, the banner will not show again for 3 months.

Instead, I am listening to the `beforeinstallprompt` event and storing the `prompt` object in a variable. After that, I'm triggering the prompt when a button is clicked.

This works as intended and a popup is shown. But I would like to know if I can change the `Add to Home Screen` text to something custom?

Thank you!

Comment: As long as I know, we can't do that yet, that's the so called `a2hs` so even the acronym suggests it that way. But I could be wrong.

Comment: I don't believe you can

Comment: how to caned https://pwa.upment.com ??? in mobile insted of "Add To Homescreen" shown "install"